# Inserting several records in the same row set ascending data

Tags: sql-server, row

My original question was no longer relevant to my new discoveries and new questions. I re-posted....possibly a no no, but I have spent sooo much time on this already. killing me.

This is my statement that returns or used to return the data I needed

Statement:

```
select  rc.[race number] AS RaceNumber,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then title1 end) as title1,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then [precinct percent] end) as PrecintPercent,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then [candidate num] end) as Winner,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then Votes end) as WinningVotes,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then party end) as WinningParty,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then leader end) as Winner1,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then CAST(winner AS tinyint) end) as WinnerSelected,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then [leader percent] end) as WinnerPercent,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then [candidate num] end) as Loser,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then Votes end) as LosingVotes,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then party end) as LosingParty,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then leader2 end) as Loser2,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then [leader2 percent] end) as LoserPercent,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then CAST(winner AS tinyint) end) as LoserSelected


from 
(
select  
        r.title1,
        r.[precinct percent],
        rc.[race number],
        rc.[candidate num],
        rc.[Votes],
        rc.[winner],
        c.[party],
        r.[leader],
        r.[leader percent],
        r.[leader2],
        r.[leader2 percent],

            row_number() over (partition by rc.[race number] order by votes desc) as seqnum
    from    dbo.[RACE CANDIDATES] rc
    inner join dbo.[CANDIDATE] c    on  rc.[candidate num]  = c.[candidate number]
    inner join dbo.[RACE] r
     on rc.[race number] = r.[race number] 

) rc
group by rc.[race number]
```

This returns 2 candidates with their vote totals and precinct percents and what race they are associated with. Now it has come to my attention that there are some races that have 3 up to 5 candidates associated with a single race, so this does not work anymore. I mean...it works, but it only returns the first 2 candidates of a race that has 3 or more candidates in it. Can this be done? I can pull the extra candidates from the [CANDIDATE] table, but not sure how to get them in the same row set or within the same race. Canddate Number is the only relation it has, so I really have no valid column to get this data from. I am searching for the column I need, but haven't found it. I have a total of 13 tables to choose from. Good grief. Hopefully this makes some sense. thanks for your comments and help!

Ok, leader and leader 2 are columns. Leader is the current candidate that has the highest votes, leader 2 is the candidate losing.

I have found the columns first name and last name, have the names I need. They were hiding in the [CANDIDATE] table. Their votes are in the [RACE CANDIDATES] table. I just do not know how to order them in my above statement so each candidate (fist name and last name) follows their vote totals is ascending order. Such as, candidate1 as the winner, candidate2 as winner2, candidate3 as losing and candidate4 losingmore. I know I am not making any sense, but I just want all the candidates in a single row and a single race. that's what I was able to accomplish with the above statement, but there are more than 2 candidates in a few of the races. I am working on it... Do you think I will need to completely re-do my statement?

Answer (score 0):

Duh.

```
select  rc.[race number] AS RaceNumber,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then title1 end) as title1,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then [precinct percent] end) as PrecintPercent,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then [candidate num] end) as Winner,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then Votes end) as WinningVotes,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then party end) as WinningParty,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then leader end) as Winner1,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then CAST(winner AS tinyint) end) as WinnerSelected,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then [leader percent] end) as WinnerPercent,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then [candidate num] end) as Loser,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then Votes end) as LosingVotes,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then party end) as LosingParty,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then leader2 end) as Loser2,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then [leader2 percent] end) as LoserPercent,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then CAST(winner AS tinyint) end) as LoserSelected,
    max(case when seqnum = 3 then [candidate num] end) as Winner3,
    max(case when seqnum = 3 then Votes end) as Winner3Votes,
    max(case when seqnum = 3 then party end) as Winner3Party,
    max(case when seqnum = 3 then [first name]end) as Winner3FirstName,
    max(case when seqnum = 3 then [last name]end) as Winner3LastName,
    max(case when seqnum = 3 then CAST(winner AS tinyint) end) as Winner3Selected,
    max(case when seqnum = 4 then [candidate num] end) as Loser4,
    max(case when seqnum = 4 then Votes end) as Loser4Votes,
    max(case when seqnum = 4 then party end) as Loser4Party,
    max(case when seqnum = 4 then [first name]end) as Loser4FirstName,
    max(case when seqnum = 4 then [last name]end) as Loser4LastName,
    max(case when seqnum = 4 then CAST(winner AS tinyint) end) as Loser4Selected


from 
(
select  
        r.title1,
        r.[precinct percent],
        rc.[race number],
        rc.[candidate num],
        rc.[Votes],
        rc.[winner],
        c.[party],
        r.[leader],
        r.[leader percent],
        r.[leader2],
        r.[leader2 percent],
        c.[first name],
        c.[last name],

            row_number() over (partition by rc.[race number] order by votes desc) as seqnum
    from    dbo.[RACE CANDIDATES] rc
    inner join dbo.[CANDIDATE] c    on  rc.[candidate num]  = c.[candidate number]
    inner join dbo.[RACE] r
     on rc.[race number] = r.[race number] 

) rc
group by rc.[race number]
```

When I path this for XML, it automatically omits the null results for the races that do not have more than candidates. Shoot...I need to have the First and Last names be in the same columns. hmmm....i'll figure it out. maybe. ha!

thanks.